# Resource on making a point and click game (no flash)

Tags: game-engine

I have played many Point and Click adventure game (Broken Sword, Sam & Max, Dott, Indiana Jones, etc ...).

I wanted to understand how to create such games. There are not much resources apart from Flash games which  don't like much. It can be just theory or specifically platform oriented tutorials.
My preference would be tutorial oriented on mobile platform like Android, but PC also will do.

Would any of you have such resources on how to make such game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I think you should read (or at least get familiar with) "[Amit's Game Programming Information](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/gameprog.html)". It is a huge FAQ about game programming in all kind of aspects and gaming approaches. And it's really useful reading.

Then, I believe the "[How to make an Adventure Game](http://www.godpatterns.com/2010/08/how-to-make-adventure-game.html)" article would be interesting for you.

Also, there is a very good document (PDF) "[A documental approach to adventure game
development](http://www.e-ucm.es/drafts/e-UCM_draft_8.pdf)". It's definitely worth to read.

Comment: hehe quite a good starting point
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are some references :

http://www.adventuregamestudio.co.uk/

http://opensludge.sourceforge.net/  (maniac mension !)

In general you have an engine that gives you the IDE and then you upload your graphic and game logic to create your game.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.visionaire-studio.net/ is the stuff you need. A Adventure Game Engine, easy to understand.