# Point and click game tutorial for android

Tags: android, game-engine

I am looking for a tutorial for android point and click game.
I looked at the comments in this post:
[resource-on-making-a-point-and-click-game-no-flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064215/resource-on-making-a-point-and-click-game-no-flash)

The links posted do not have any thing to do with android.
I also read: 
[android game tutorial](http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/)

However, it is not a point and click game. So, I am looking for a tutorial about Point and Click game specifically for android platform.

Edit: By "point and click", I refer to a game style similar to the PC. However, I do not want a mouse pointer, that would be weird on Android. I just want the user to be able to touch various widgets/ objects on the game screen, and interact with them (by tapping on them).

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-i,770.html) will be helpful. It will have android 2d and 3d tutorials. Also a rock paper scissors game will be present in the same tutorial.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a search engine for tutorials. Google and Bing both specialize in searches. SO is for *specific, concise** programming questions. Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: I know posts like these are usually closed as "off-topic" in SO. It is really sad. I am asking this question in this forum after many hours of googling and reading game tutorials for android. I could not find any tutorial suitable for my problem. Anyway, hope I will get nice references before it is closed. If you think it is off-topic and you want to close it, that's your choice and I respect that.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 As per your suggestion, I am referring to this link: http://www.scirra.com/construct2

Comment: @Robik I can do you one better and link you to the tutorial site.  They have many tutorials specific to Android development, and their beginner tutorials have different versions (top-down, side-scroller, etc.), which will give you a great sense of the software.  The free version of their platform covers most things.  The paid version has additional layers, which are nice for more advanced tricks.  You should also check out their showcase games, to see what others have made for Andriod.  http://www.scirra.com/tutorials

Comment: Is there anything specific to "point and click android game"?

Comment: @Robik The beginner tutorial is enough to figure out how most point-and-click stuff works.  Page 5 has the first mouse-click event: http://www.scirra.com/tutorials/37/beginners-guide-to-construct-2/page-5. There is a way to set an event to happen when you click an object, also (for example, when you click a monster, it dies).  Here is an easy-to-follow Whack A Mole: http://www.scirra.com/forum/whack-a-mole-game-construct-2_topic43554.html. Usually you build the full game, first.  Then, you get into an Android tutorial to add everything necessary for it to work on Android. It's an easy process.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it's time for some coding!

Comment: I just read this: http://www.scirra.com/forum/construct-2-and-android_topic53409.html. 1. Is the game I develop in construct 2 guaranteed to work in android? 2. Is the entire process completely free of charge (from sprites to adding audio etc. to publishing to app market)? 3. Will the performance be fast enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Construct 2](http://www.scirra.com/construct2) is a good place to start. They have many [tutorials](http://scirra.com/tutorials) specific to Android development, and their beginner tutorials have different versions (top-down, side-scroller, etc.), which will give you a great sense of the software. The free version of their platform covers most things. The paid version has additional layers, which are nice for more advanced tricks. You should also check out their showcase games, to see [what others have made for Andriod](http://www.scirra.com/forum/construct-2-and-android_topic53409.html).

The beginner tutorial is enough to figure out how most point-and-click stuff works. [Page 5 of the beginner's tutorial](http://scirra.com/tutorials/37/beginners-guide-to-construct-2/page-5.) has the first mouse-click event There is a way to set an event to happen when you click an object, also (for example, when you click a monster, it dies). [Here is an easy-to-follow Whack A Mole](http://scirra.com/forum/whack-a-mole-game-construct-2_topic43554.html). Usually you build the full game, first. Then, you get into an [Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) to add everything necessary for it to work on Android. It's an easy process for a skilled developer, but it requires that you venture out of the user-friendly, point-and-click game construction kits like Construct 2.

From the perspective of a developer, your best bet is going to be Java.  It's probably the most Android-friendly language out there.  It will be the most stable, fastest, and easiest to learn in most cases.  Also, it will require the least on the part of the user (for example, users won't need a custom browser or Jetpack, Air or anything--the user won't need to install anything other than your app).  The top hit on google, today, is here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/06/android-game-development-tutorials.html.

There are other, easy-to-find places you can read up on getting started with Java for Android game development--meaning this question will likely be closed.  It will require reading other people's code, and you should probably start by familiarizing yourself with Java.  After you have spent a good chunk of time studying Java, you can go through tutorials and understand them and get creative with different customizations and applications for various of code.  The top hit on YouTube is a point-and-destroy, Whack-a-Mole-type game, with source code, for example, which may suit your purpose.  I can't completely tell by your description, though, because people don't generally click unless they are using a mouse, and an Android doesn't use a mouse afaik.  :)  You should consider updating your question and getting into some gritty detail.

Comment: I just read this: http://www.scirra.com/forum/construct-2-and-android_topic53409.html. 1. Is the game I develop in construct 2 guaranteed to work in android? 2. Is the entire process completely free of charge (from sprites to adding audio etc. to publishing to app market)? 3. Will the performance be fast enough?

Comment: I edited by question to explain about what I meant by "point and click". Also, I am just trying to learn game development. I have got few "point and click" game ideas, but I can't go into details because I don't have a design as of right now.

Comment: @Robik In life, there are no guarantees. Phonegap is pretty safe, though: http://www.scirra.com/tutorials/71/how-to-make-native-phone-apps-with-construct-2-and-phonegap; alternatively, the Android-specific docs: http://www.scirra.com/tutorials/367/how-to-make-android-games. This is also useful: http://www.scirra.com/tutorials/247/how-to-preview-on-a-local-network. According to the store, http://www.scirra.com/store/construct-2, publishing does not require a license. Making money might. If you can make a good game, getting it to work on Android would be worthwhile, I think. There's always Java.

Comment: @Robik As far as speed is concerned, you should check out the demo games.  On some older phones, the games may not work as quickly.  What I have seen is that each month, their Android games get significantly better.  A few months ago, I was posting 'how-the-Hell-do-I-port-to-Android!?' questions.  Now, questions are looking more like 'how do I make it cooler'.

Comment: Well I am following the beginner's tutorial now and it is real fun and easy! I would surely not wanna code those things in java. I might ask more questions after the tutorial.

Comment: I didn't quite get the part: "According to the store, scirra.com/store/construct-2, publishing does not require a license. Making money might." So I ask one simple question: Can I develop and publish/sell an android app using Construct 2 without any charge at all?

Comment: @Robik I think publishing is free, making a small amount of money is free, making a moderate amount of money requires a private license (which costs money), and making a large amount of money requires a corporate license (which also costs money).  So, your simple answer has different answers depending on the context you put it in.  The simple answer is no because you're only saying *publishing and selling*.  The simple answer becomes yes when you talk about *monetizing* your product--coming over the initial investment in building it (time, for example).  So, I think the answer is yes.

Comment: Still confused. So, do I need to purchase the license to sell it on the google play? or can I sell it on google play without purchasing the license?

Comment: I read http://www.scirra.com/store/construct-2. Seems like we need to purchase at least a personal license to be able to sell it on android play. Am I right?

Comment: Hi there, Tom from Scirra here.  You will require a license if you want to make any money from your games.  You're not allowed to make money from your creations with the free edition.  Any other questions best directed towards our support email address!